# Using socket.io with a standalone javascript file

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'd like to use socket.io in a javascript file. How can I do this?

The only way I currently know of using socket.io, as a client is doing

`<script src="[server?]/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` inside an html file.

Comment: You could use socket.io in conjunction with nodejs (http://nodejs.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including a javascript within a javascript file is not naturally accomplished, because it's not really needed in most scenarios (you just include them both on your html page, for example).  You probably have to rethink the way you're executing javascript, but I do believe there is a library designed to this (for whatever reason that may be).

include.js I think it is called.

EDIT: and in the event you're thinking dynamically adding javascript, you can just create a script element and append it to document.head.  Um, for example:

```
document.head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var js = document.createElement('script');
js.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
js.setAttribute('src','http://my/src/file');
document.head.appendChild(js);
```

...just off the top of my head.

Comment: I'll try to explain my design. I'm trying to make an Angular.js front-end that will communicate with my node.js backend over sockets. Angular lets you have javascript files as sort of a "code-behind" for your html. I would like the socket communication to be in these files. Is this a good design?

Comment: I'll let someone familiar with angular answer, I suppose, because I'm not sure.  But if you're using nodejs just include socket.io and do your communication directly (by yourself, I guess), sort of like what Jason was getting at I think in his above comment.

Answer (score 0):

In my html file I did:

`<script src="http://[node server]:[port]/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`
`

and in my .js file, I did

`io.socket = io.connect('http://[node server]:[port]');`

and it worked.

I suppose "a standalone javascript file" is inaccurate, because I'm building a web front-end. I meant that it was just a .js file with nothing like `node.js` running it.